# Compiled Binding to IsChecked checkbox

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I've got CheckBoxes in my list I'm trying to use compiled binding to bind IsChecked propertie...

So I tried this:

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="local:RDO">
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <CheckBox Content="{x:Bind Content}" IsChecked="{x:Bind Check}"/>
     </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

And my model class is like this:

```
class RDO {
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public Boolean Check { get; set; }
}
```

But it doesn't work and return an error saying

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error       Invalid binding path 'Check' : Cannot bind type 'System.Boolean' to 'System.Nullable(System.Boolean)' without a converter

How could I fix this?

and what's difference between Boolean and Nullable(Boolean)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your model must implement its Property `Check` like

```
 class RDO {
public string Content { get; set; }
public Boolean? Check { get; set; }
}
```

See the `?` on `Boolean?` ?
Nullable is a wrapper for value types (`struct`) so these can have a value of `null` (which value types cannot have by default).
This is a requirement in your particular case to use binding functionality.

For further studies:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Comment: tnx bro ,I can understand now

Comment: You're welcome! But please see that your particular `Nullable` can have other values than ` true` or `false` now! It can now be `null`, too, so don't forget that.